# Keeping cookie data separate

Tags: firefox, browser, privacy, cookies

If I want to keep Google from knowing what I do on Amazon and Facebook, will making copies of my browser software in separate folders and renaming the executable for each site work? In brief, will the renamed browser communicate with the other browsers via cookies?

Example: I have my base browser and it's homepage is Google. So, Google, YouTube, and Gmail cookies reside in this instance. I make a second folder called Browser2 and rename the executable 'browser2.exe' instead of 'browser.exe.' The home page for this one is Amazon. I make a third folder called Browser2 and rename the executable 'browser3.exe' for a Facebook homepage. Will this keep the 3 web-giants from knowing what I am doing on the others?

Comment: I doubt that there is a universal answer to this question; you need to say what browser(s) you’re talking about. … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

[For firefox, yes](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/dedicated-profiles-firefox-installation) (thought I'd not recommend renaming the exe), but you probably don't need to.

Consider using multiple [Firefox Profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) for the [same installation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

Each profile contains

- Bookmarks, Downloads and Browsing History
- Passwords
- Site-specific preferences
- Search engines
- Autocomplete history
- Cookies
- DOM storage
- Extensions
- Security certificate settings
- Security device settings
- Download actions
- Stored session
- Toolbar customization
- User preferences